# specific php script to run upon selecting an option from dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have numerous different PHP scripts that pull out different information from a MySQL database. Currently you have to load a page to bring up the SQL queries within it.

I would like to create a dropdown menu such that when one of the options is clicked, it runs a specific php script and displays the result on the same page, below the drop down list.

Below is the HTML I have so far (I am using a template I found at: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

I want it so that say if Billing is clicked the php file "billingquery.php" will be run and displayed, or if the All Users option is selected, the php file "allusersquery.php" will be run and displayed.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUserGroup(str)
{
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
    // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getusergroup.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="usergroups" onchange="showUserGroup(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a User Group:</option>
<option value="1">Billing</option>
<option value="2">All Users</option>
<option value="3">All Data</option>
<option value="4">Next Option</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>User Group information and access rights will be listed here.</b>    </div>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Why not use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?  All you need to do is an ajax call that will take the result and repopulate your drop down.

Comment: Thanks. Although, I wouldn't know where to even start with that! Is it possible to assign an action to each selection so that when it is selected it will run that particular php script?

Comment: Start with the [internet](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

First, add the jQuery library to your html - the best way is to load it from a CDN like google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then, add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[name="usergroups"]').on('change', function() {

    var ajaxMethod = "default.php";

    switch($(this).val())
    {
    case "1":
      ajaxMethod = "billingquery.php";
      break;
    case "2":
      ajaxMethod = "allusers.php";
      break;                
    case "3":
      ajaxMethod = "alldata.php";
      break;                
    case "4":
      ajaxMethod = "nextoption.php";
      break;      
   }

   $("#txtHint b").load(ajaxMethod);

});​
</script>
```

jQuery is very powerful and really changes to help developers "turn the light bulb on" in regards to javascript development.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wtvamp/cPuWZ/4/)

Comment: Hi Warren,
Thanks so much for this answer, this looks exactly right! However, when I now select an option from the dropdown list it does not do anything.
What does default.php in the above refer to?
Ultimately, when case 1 is selected, I would like the sql queries contained within billingquery.php to be lsited below; when case 2 is selected, the sql queries contained within allusers.php to be displayed and so on.
From what I understand of the code it should do this but can't be sure!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: default.php is a default script that could display anything if the user selects this option:  <option value="">Select a User Group:</option>  It could just be a message that says "Please select an option from the list" or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks. However, I still can't get it to update the page with the queries contained within each file (billingquery.php / allusers.php) upon selection from the drop down list? Cheers.